# Extend MySQLi Class PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, mysqli, global

I have downloaded the SafeMySQL class which I will post below. I would like to extend this database class to all of my other classes throughout the site that call queries. Currently, I have the main db connector set as a global variable, but I have to call it inside each class constructor and all of the class's methods. Surely there has to be an easier way?

Here is the DB class:

```
class SafeMySQL
{

private $conn;
private $stats;
private $emode;
private $exname;

private $defaults = array(
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'user'      => '',
    'pass'      => '',
    'db'        => '',
    'port'      => NULL,
    'socket'    => NULL,
    'pconnect'  => FALSE,
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'errmode'   => 'error', //or exception
    'exception' => 'Exception', //Exception class name
);

const RESULT_ASSOC = MYSQLI_ASSOC;
const RESULT_NUM   = MYSQLI_NUM;

public function __construct($opt = array())
{
    $opt = array_merge($this->defaults,$opt);

    $this->emode  = $opt['errmode'];
    $this->exname = $opt['exception'];

    if ($opt['pconnect'])
    {
        $opt['host'] = "p:".$opt['host'];
    }

    @$this->conn = mysqli_connect($opt['host'], $opt['user'], $opt['pass'], $opt['db'], $opt['port'], $opt['socket']);
    if ( !$this->conn )
    {
        $this->error(mysqli_connect_errno()." ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    mysqli_set_charset($this->conn, $opt['charset']) or $this->error(mysqli_error($this->conn));
    unset($opt); // I am paranoid
}

/**
 * Conventional function to run a query with placeholders. A mysqli_query wrapper with placeholders support
 * 
 * Examples:
 * $db->query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id=?i", $id);
 *
 * @param string $query - an SQL query with placeholders
 * @param mixed  $arg,... unlimited number of arguments to match placeholders in the query
 * @return resource|FALSE whatever mysqli_query returns
 */
public function query()
{   
    return $this->rawQuery($this->prepareQuery(func_get_args()));
}

/**
 * Conventional function to fetch single row. 
 * 
 * @param resource $result - myqli result
 * @param int $mode - optional fetch mode, RESULT_ASSOC|RESULT_NUM, default RESULT_ASSOC
 * @return array|FALSE whatever mysqli_fetch_array returns
 */
public function fetch($result,$mode=self::RESULT_ASSOC)
{
    return mysqli_fetch_array($result, $mode);
}

/**
 * Conventional function to get number of affected rows. 
 * 
 * @return int whatever mysqli_affected_rows returns
 */
public function affectedRows()
{
    return mysqli_affected_rows ($this->conn);
}

/**
 * Conventional function to get last insert id. 
 * 
 * @return int whatever mysqli_insert_id returns
 */
public function insertId()
{
    return mysqli_insert_id($this->conn);
}

/**
 * Conventional function to get number of rows in the resultset. 
 * 
 * @param resource $result - myqli result
 * @return int whatever mysqli_num_rows returns
 */
public function numRows($result)
{
    return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}

/**
 * Conventional function to free the resultset. 
 */
public function free($result)
{
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/**
 * Helper function to get scalar value right out of query and optional arguments
 * 
 * Examples:
 * $name = $db->getOne("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=1");
 * $name = $db->getOne("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=?i", $id);
 *
 * @param string $query - an SQL query with placeholders
 * @param mixed  $arg,... unlimited number of arguments to match placeholders in the query
 * @return string|FALSE either first column of the first row of resultset or FALSE if none found
 */
public function getOne()
{
    $query = $this->prepareQuery(func_get_args());
    if ($res = $this->rawQuery($query))
    {
        $row = $this->fetch($res);
        if (is_array($row)) {
            return reset($row);
        }
        $this->free($res);
    }
    return FALSE;
}

/**
 * Helper function to get single row right out of query and optional arguments
 * 
 * Examples:
 * $data = $db->getRow("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1");
 * $data = $db->getOne("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?i", $id);
 *
 * @param string $query - an SQL query with placeholders
 * @param mixed  $arg,... unlimited number of arguments to match placeholders in the query
 * @return array|FALSE either associative array contains first row of resultset or FALSE if none found
 */
public function getRow()
{
    $query = $this->prepareQuery(func_get_args());
    if ($res = $this->rawQuery($query)) {
        $ret = $this->fetch($res);
        $this->free($res);
        return $ret;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

/**
 * Helper function to get single column right out of query and optional arguments
 * 
 * Examples:
 * $ids = $db->getCol("SELECT id FROM table WHERE cat=1");
 * $ids = $db->getCol("SELECT id FROM tags WHERE tagname = ?s", $tag);
 *
 * @param string $query - an SQL query with placeholders
 * @param mixed  $arg,... unlimited number of arguments to match placeholders in the query
 * @return array|FALSE either enumerated array of first fields of all rows of resultset or FALSE if none found
 */
public function getCol()
{
    $ret   = array();
    $query = $this->prepareQuery(func_get_args());
    if ( $res = $this->rawQuery($query) )
    {
        while($row = $this->fetch($res))
        {
            $ret[] = reset($row);
        }
        $this->free($res);
    }
    return $ret;
}

/**
 * Helper function to get all the rows of resultset right out of query and optional arguments
 * 
 * Examples:
 * $data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM table");
 * $data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ?i,?i", $start, $rows);
 *
 * @param string $query - an SQL query with placeholders
 * @param mixed  $arg,... unlimited number of arguments to match placeholders in the query
 * @return array enumerated 2d array contains the resultset. Empty if no rows found. 
 */
public function getAll()
{
    $ret   = array();
    $query = $this->prepareQuery(func_get_args());
    if ( $res = $this->rawQuery($query) )
    {
        while($row = $this->fetch($res))
        {
            $ret[] = $row;
        }
        $this->free($res);
    }
    return $ret;
}

/**
 * Helper function to get all the rows of resultset into indexed array right out of query and optional arguments
 * 
 * Examples:
 * $data = $db->getInd("id", "SELECT * FROM table");
 * $data = $db->getInd("id", "SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ?i,?i", $start, $rows);
 *
 * @param string $index - name of the field which value is used to index resulting array
 * @param string $query - an SQL query with placeholders
 * @param mixed  $arg,... unlimited number of arguments to match placeholders in the query
 * @return array - associative 2d array contains the resultset. Empty if no rows found. 
 */
public function getInd()
{
    $args  = func_get_args();
    $index = array_shift($args);
    $query = $this->prepareQuery($args);

    $ret = array();
    if ( $res = $this->rawQuery($query) )
    {
        while($row = $this->fetch($res))
        {
            $ret[$row[$index]] = $row;
        }
        $this->free($res);
    }
    return $ret;
}

/**
 * Helper function to get a dictionary-style array right out of query and optional arguments
 * 
 * Examples:
 * $data = $db->getIndCol("name", "SELECT name, id FROM cities");
 *
 * @param string $index - name of the field which value is used to index resulting array
 * @param string $query - an SQL query with placeholders
 * @param mixed  $arg,... unlimited number of arguments to match placeholders in the query
 * @return array - associative array contains key=value pairs out of resultset. Empty if no rows found. 
 */
public function getIndCol()
{
    $args  = func_get_args();
    $index = array_shift($args);
    $query = $this->prepareQuery($args);

    $ret = array();
    if ( $res = $this->rawQuery($query) )
    {
        while($row = $this->fetch($res))
        {
            $key = $row[$index];
            unset($row[$index]);
            $ret[$key] = reset($row);
        }
        $this->free($res);
    }
    return $ret;
}

/**
 * Function to parse placeholders either in the full query or a query part
 * unlike native prepared statements, allows ANY query part to be parsed
 * 
 * useful for debug
 * and EXTREMELY useful for conditional query building
 * like adding various query parts using loops, conditions, etc.
 * already parsed parts have to be added via ?p placeholder
 * 
 * Examples:
 * $query = $db->parse("SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo=?s AND bar=?s", $foo, $bar);
 * echo $query;
 * 
 * if ($foo) {
 *     $qpart = $db->parse(" AND foo=?s", $foo);
 * }
 * $data = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM table WHERE bar=?s ?p", $bar, $qpart);
 *
 * @param string $query - whatever expression contains placeholders
 * @param mixed  $arg,... unlimited number of arguments to match placeholders in the expression
 * @return string - initial expression with placeholders substituted with data. 
 */
public function parse()
{
    return $this->prepareQuery(func_get_args());
}

/**
 * function to implement whitelisting feature
 * sometimes we can't allow a non-validated user-supplied data to the query even through placeholder
 * especially if it comes down to SQL OPERATORS
 * 
 * Example:
 *
 * $order = $db->whiteList($_GET['order'], array('name','price'));
 * $dir   = $db->whiteList($_GET['dir'],   array('ASC','DESC'));
 * if (!$order || !dir) {
 *     throw new http404(); //non-expected values should cause 404 or similar response
 * }
 * $sql  = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ?p ?p LIMIT ?i,?i"
 * $data = $db->getArr($sql, $order, $dir, $start, $per_page);
 * 
 * @param string $iinput   - field name to test
 * @param  array  $allowed - an array with allowed variants
 * @param  string $default - optional variable to set if no match found. Default to false.
 * @return string|FALSE    - either sanitized value or FALSE
 */
public function whiteList($input,$allowed,$default=FALSE)
{
    $found = array_search($input,$allowed);
    return ($found === FALSE) ? $default : $allowed[$found];
}

/**
 * function to filter out arrays, for the whitelisting purposes
 * useful to pass entire superglobal to the INSERT or UPDATE query
 * OUGHT to be used for this purpose, 
 * as there could be fields to which user should have no access to.
 * 
 * Example:
 * $allowed = array('title','url','body','rating','term','type');
 * $data    = $db->filterArray($_POST,$allowed);
 * $sql     = "INSERT INTO ?n SET ?u";
 * $db->query($sql,$table,$data);
 * 
 * @param  array $input   - source array
 * @param  array $allowed - an array with allowed field names
 * @return array filtered out source array
 */
public function filterArray($input,$allowed)
{
    foreach(array_keys($input) as $key )
    {
        if ( !in_array($key,$allowed) )
        {
            unset($input[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $input;
}

/**
 * Function to get last executed query. 
 * 
 * @return string|NULL either last executed query or NULL if were none
 */
public function lastQuery()
{
    $last = end($this->stats);
    return $last['query'];
}

/**
 * Function to get all query statistics. 
 * 
 * @return array contains all executed queries with timings and errors
 */
public function getStats()
{
    return $this->stats;
}

/**
 * private function which actually runs a query against Mysql server.
 * also logs some stats like profiling info and error message
 * 
 * @param string $query - a regular SQL query
 * @return mysqli result resource or FALSE on error
 */
private function rawQuery($query)
{
    $start = microtime(TRUE);
    $res   = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
    $timer = microtime(TRUE) - $start;

    $this->stats[] = array(
        'query' => $query,
        'start' => $start,
        'timer' => $timer,
    );
    if (!$res)
    {
        $error = mysqli_error($this->conn);

        end($this->stats);
        $key = key($this->stats);
        $this->stats[$key]['error'] = $error;
        $this->cutStats();

        $this->error("$error. Full query: [$query]");
    }
    $this->cutStats();
    return $res;
}

private function prepareQuery($args)
{
    $query = '';
    $raw   = array_shift($args);
    $array = preg_split('~(\?[nsiuap])~u',$raw,null,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $anum  = count($args);
    $pnum  = floor(count($array) / 2);
    if ( $pnum != $anum )
    {
        $this->error("Number of args ($anum) doesn't match number of placeholders ($pnum) in [$raw]");
    }

    foreach ($array as $i => $part)
    {
        if ( ($i % 2) == 0 )
        {
            $query .= $part;
            continue;
        }

        $value = array_shift($args);
        switch ($part)
        {
            case '?n':
                $part = $this->escapeIdent($value);
                break;
            case '?s':
                $part = $this->escapeString($value);
                break;
            case '?i':
                $part = $this->escapeInt($value);
                break;
            case '?a':
                $part = $this->createIN($value);
                break;
            case '?u':
                $part = $this->createSET($value);
                break;
            case '?p':
                $part = $value;
                break;
        }
        $query .= $part;
    }
    return $query;
}

private function escapeInt($value)
{
    if ($value === NULL)
    {
        return 'NULL';
    }
    if(!is_numeric($value))
    {
        $this->error("Integer (?i) placeholder expects numeric value, ".gettype($value)." given");
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (is_float($value))
    {
        $value = number_format($value, 0, '.', ''); // may lose precision on big numbers
    } 
    return $value;
}

private function escapeString($value)
{
    if ($value === NULL)
    {
        return 'NULL';
    }
    return  "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn,$value)."'";
}

private function escapeIdent($value)
{
    if ($value)
    {
        return "`".str_replace("`","``",$value)."`";
    } else {
        $this->error("Empty value for identifier (?n) placeholder");
    }
}

private function createIN($data)
{
    if (!is_array($data))
    {
        $this->error("Value for IN (?a) placeholder should be array");
        return;
    }
    if (!$data)
    {
        return 'NULL';
    }
    $query = $comma = '';
    foreach ($data as $value)
    {
        $query .= $comma.$this->escapeString($value);
        $comma  = ",";
    }
    return $query;
}

private function createSET($data)
{
    if (!is_array($data))
    {
        $this->error("SET (?u) placeholder expects array, ".gettype($data)." given");
        return;
    }
    if (!$data)
    {
        $this->error("Empty array for SET (?u) placeholder");
        return;
    }
    $query = $comma = '';
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $query .= $comma.$this->escapeIdent($key).'='.$this->escapeString($value);
        $comma  = ",";
    }
    return $query;
}

private function error($err)
{
    $err  = __CLASS__.": ".$err;

    if ( $this->emode == 'error' )
    {
        $err .= ". Error initiated in ".$this->caller().", thrown";
        trigger_error($err,E_USER_ERROR);
    } else {
        throw new $this->exname($err);
    }
}

private function caller()
{
    $trace  = debug_backtrace();
    $caller = '';
    foreach ($trace as $t)
    {
        if ( isset($t['class']) && $t['class'] == __CLASS__ )
        {
            $caller = $t['file']." on line ".$t['line'];
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $caller;
}

/**
 * On a long run we can eat up too much memory with mere statsistics
 * Let's keep it at reasonable size, leaving only last 100 entries.
 */
private function cutStats()
{
    if ( count($this->stats) > 100 )
    {
        reset($this->stats);
        $first = key($this->stats);
        unset($this->stats[$first]);
    }
}
}




//HOW I'M CURRENTLY CONNECTING TO THE DATABASE & CREATING GLOBAL VAR
global $db;

$db = new SafeMySQL('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');
```

This is the class I would like to extend the above database class to:

```
class News
{

public $news_id;
var $author;
var $title;
var $body;
var $date;
var $comments_count;


    function __construct($id)
    {   
        global $db;

        $row = $db->getRow('SELECT * 
                    FROM news_articles 
                    WHERE id = ?i', $id);

        $this->news_id = $row[id];
        $this->author = $row[author];
        $this->title = $row[title];
        $this->body = $row[body];
        $this->date = $row[date];
        $this->comments_count = $this->countComments(); 
    }


    public static function getAllArticles(){
        global $db;

        $all_articles_array = $db->getAll('SELECT id 
                    FROM news_articles ORDER BY date DESC');

        return $all_articles_array;
    }
```

Comment: What error did you run into with rawQuery? this function is not intended to be called from application code. `query()` method have to be called instead, supplied with SQL query with appropriate placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use the word 'extends'. It has a very special meaning and may confuse a reader. You rather need to 'use' another class' instance in this  .

Although in my opinion using `global` keyword for the site-wide global variables is all right, you'd be teared in pieces if spotted by local 'global police'. So, it's safer to pass a `$db` object into constructor and assign it as a class property:

```
class News
{

    public $news_id;
    private $db;
    var $author;
    var $title;
    var $body;
    var $date;
    var $comments_count;

    function __construct($db, $id)
    {   
        $this->db = $db;

        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM news_articles WHERE id = ?i';
        $row = $this->db->getRow($sql, $id);

        $this->news_id = $row['id'];
        $this->author = $row['author'];
        $this->title = $row['title'];
        $this->body = $row['body'];
        $this->date = $row['date'];
        $this->comments_count = $this->countComments(); 
    }

    public static function getAllArticlesIds()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT id FROM news_articles ORDER BY date DESC';
        return $thus->db->getCol($sql);
    }
}
```

Note that I renamed the other method and used `getCol()` method here as you are selecting only one column.

However i don't quite understand why do you set some properties in the constructor. It seems you are confusing **two** classes - News and Article. It's for the single Article object you have to initialize it's properties in the constructor. While for the News I doubt it is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem. However, I notice that SafeMySql does not provide the connection handle. It might help to add this:

```
/**
* Function to get the connection handle.
* Addition to original SafeDB.
*
* Examples:
* mysqli_autocommit($db->getHandle(),FALSE);
* mysqli_commit($db->getHandle());
*
* @param string $getHandle - an SQL connection handle
* @return object
*/  
public function getHandle()
    {
    return $this->conn;
    }
```